# I am unable to find all my favorites that I have done in the individual question

Tags: feature-request, android-app, bookmarks

After searching favorited question everywhere I am unable to find FAVOURITE section in the app. Please do something for this.

Comment: I haven't checked that this question already existed. I have just posted in "request feature" section of the app. Can you understand me!!

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to delete the post. Unknowingly given a comment as a answer!! 

Comment: Please relax, we're not blaming you for anything. You can delete the post by opening it in a browser (ironically, deleting one's post is one of the other missing features).

Comment: After opening in the browser. The post looks a lot colourful and able to see your pic, that was awesome. And after returning to the app it looks blue and white (dull). Can I request for a theme changing ability and picture of a commented person? Please check if this question exist.